# HAProxy Configuration - How to make TCP connection sticky (Node.js, socket.io, websocket, FlashSocket)

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp, amazon-ec2, haproxy

I have setup HAProxy for EC2 server where i'm running my nodejs two server on port 3005 and 3006. we have setup this for our multiplayer game. we have used socket.io for our realtime event update on client side and server side. HAProxy is working correctly with "balance source" (I have added working copy of my HAProxy Configuration), in source balancer problem is that its goes all event on same server each and ever time. so i have 40 computer setup in my network so all 40 computer event goes to 3005 port. its not changing port when i'm coming next day.  I would like to setup TCP connection sticky with TCP mode in haproxy. is there any way to do with balance roundrobin? I have added my current setting files here. we also trying to used cookie but its not working in our case because we have used mode as tcp.

Also we have flash game which used to load flash policy from port 3843.

Here added my haproxy configuration.

```
global
debug
log 127.0.0.1   local0         # Enable per-instance logging of events and traffic.
log 127.0.0.1   local1 notice  # only send important events
nbproc  1
maxconn 65536
pidfile /var/run/haproxy.pid

defaults
log global
srvtimeout 300s
timeout connect 5s
timeout queue   5s
timeout server 1h
timeout tunnel  1h

frontend flash_policy
bind 0.0.0.0:843
timeout client 5s
default_backend nodejs_flashpolicy

frontend wwws
bind 0.0.0.0:3000 ssl crt /home/certificate/final.crt
timeout client 1h
default_backend flashsocket_backend

tcp-request inspect-delay 500ms
tcp-request content accept if HTTP
use_backend flashsocket_backend if !HTTP

backend flashsocket_backend
mode tcp
option log-health-checks
balance source
cookie JSESSIONID insert indirect nocache
server 3006Game serverip:3006 cookie socket1 weight 1 maxconn 32536 check
server 3005Game serverip:3005 cookie socket2 weight 1 maxconn 32536 check

backend nodejs_flashpolicy
server flashpolicy serverip:3843 weight 1 maxconn 65536 check

# Configuration for HAProxy Stats
listen stats :1900
mode http
timeout client 1h
stats enable
stats hide-version
stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics
stats uri /
stats auth alpesh:alpesh
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible by using following options in backend:

```
stick-table type ip size 50k expire 10m
stick on src
```